# g++ ignoring specified C++ standard

Tags: compiler-errors, g++

I am running g++ with the compile flag `-std=c++17`

despite this, I am getting errors that typically mean that the compiler doesn't have access to C++17 additions

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
    int lo = 1;
    int hi = 99;
    int val = std::clamp(-3, lo, hi);
    std::cout << val << '\n';
}
```

I compile with

```
g++ -std=c++17 -c -o test.o test.cpp
```

and get the error:

```cpp
test.cpp: In function 'int main()':
test.cpp:7:15: error: 'clamp' is not a member of 'std'
     int val = std::clamp(-3, lo, hi);
               ^~~
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the compiler wasn't capable of doing C++17, I suspect it would complain about the *flag* you gave it.

I often get that error when I've forgotten to include required headers, `algorithm` in your specific case.

---

Other than that, all I can suggest is to include the `gcc` version in your question and provide the smallest complete program that exhibits the problem, allowing us to more easily diagnose it.

The version is important since, as per `gcc` docs:

> GCC 9.1 was the first release with non-experimental C++17 support, so the API and ABI of features added in C++17 is only stable since that release.

Hence, if you're on an earlier version, you may find certain irregularities.

---

To assist you, this small sample of mine seems to work fine so I'd suggest trying to compile it as well:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
    int lo = 1;
    int hi = 99;
    int val = std::clamp(-3, lo, hi);
    std::cout << val << '\n';
}
```

The following transcript shows how I did it on my machine:

```
pax:~> g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu 9.3.0-10ubuntu2) 9.3.0
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

pax:~> g++ --std=c++17 -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -o prog prog.cpp

pax:~> ./prog
1
```

---

Another possibility: even though you state quite clearly you're compiling with that flag, check it. The error I get when using C++14 is very similar:

```
prog.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
prog.cpp:7:20: error: ‘clamp’ is not a member of ‘std’
    7 |     int val = std::clamp(-3, lo, hi);
      |                    ^~~~~
```

Temporarily replace the offending line with:

```cpp
 std::cout << __cplusplus << '\n';
```

and ensure you get `201703`.

Comment: @F53: what does `g++ --version` give you? Make sure it's recent enough. Otherwise your `gcc` command is being modified somehow to remove/ignore the `-std=c++17` flag.

Comment: it gives me 6.3.0, oof, guess that's the problem

Comment: @F53: I would say so. If you look at the libdocs for 6.3 algorithms (https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-6.3.0/libstdc++/api/a01804.html), there's not much in there. A search for `clamp` reveals nothing.